# Two of my pages have a small gap under the footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

All of my other pages do not have this gap, I am using Bootstrap but am a beginner. What do you think it could be? Is the whole page coded wrong because the contact form works fine, just when I am on a mobile device I can see a very thin white line under the footer.

```html
<div class="section-md">
  <div class="container container-normal">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <?php if (isset($_SESSION[ 'contact_success'])): ?>
            <h2>Message Sent</h2>
            <div class="alert alert-success">

              Your information has been received. We will contact you within 1 business day.
            </div>
            <a href="<?= site_url() ?>" class="btn btn-default">Back to Homepage</a>
            <?php unset($_SESSION[ 'contact_success']) ?>

            <?php else: ?>

            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p class="text-muted">This is our contact page...</p>
            <hr>
            <div class="error-msg alert alert-danger cnt-error">
              <p>Please fill in all required fields.</p>
            </div>
            <form id="contact_form" action="<?= site_url() ?>contact/save" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name*</label>
                <input id="cnt_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email*</label>
                <input id="cnt_email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="user@example.com">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject*</label>
                <input id="cnt_subject" type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="This website rocks">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="form-label">Comments*</label>
                <textarea id="cnt_message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Enter a few questions in here..."></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <a href="<?= site_url() ?>" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.form-group -->
            </form>
            <?php endif ?>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.section-md -->
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: By the look of the code I posted, can you notice any mistakes that would cause this? I am confused because like 10 other pages do not have this small gap under the footer which is only visible on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had margin in your 
Let's try this code

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Add that to custom.css?

Comment: Yes, Of Course! You may add this on the top of your custom.css

Comment: Like I said, most of my pages do not have this issue. If I add it in custom.css, all pages would be affected :(